# mutualism system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Two species $x,y$ are in symbiosis if an increase of either population leads to an increase in growth rate of the other. Thus we assume 
$$x'=M(x,y)x $$ $$y'=N(x,y)y$$ with $\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}>0 ,\frac{\partial N}{\partial y}>0 \ \ \ $   and $\ \ \ x,y \geq 0$.

We also suppose that the total food supply is limited;

Thus for some $A>0 , B>0$, we have $$M(x,y)<0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \text if \ \ \ \ x>A \\N(x,y)<0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \text if \ \ \ \ y>B.$$

Assuming that the intersection of the curves $M^{-1}(0), N^{-1}(0)$ are finite , and that all are tranverse, show that:

1) Every solution tends to an equilibrium in the region $0<x<A, 0<y<B$

2) There are no sources.

3) There is at least one sink

4) if $\frac{\partial M}{\partial x}<0 $ and $\frac{\partial N}{\partial y}<0 $, there is a unique sink $Z$ and Z is the $\omega$ -limit set for all $(x,y)$ with $x>0, y>0$.

---

This is a homework question, and I need some hint to solve this problem.

- I'm not sure what the curve $M^-1(0), N^{-1}(0)$  looks like and where does it start from. I'm sure that the curves are the nullcline.
- Does $M(x,y)<0 \ \ \ \ \text if \ x>A $ does means that $\frac{\partial M}{\partial x} <0$ when $x>A$ ?
- In question 1, I know that at the point (0,0) is a source and the region where x>A and y>B, the direction are going inside of the rectangle $0<x<A, 0<y<B$ So there must be an equilibrium point.
- for 2 and 3 I don't know what to do.

Comment: Are you aware that your system, written under the form $\tfrac{x'}{x}=M(x,y)$ $\tfrac{y'}{y}=N(x,y)$ introduces exponentials in a natural way?

Comment: no?..I don't get it..

Comment: What is the general primitive function of $\tfrac{x'}{x}$ ?

Comment: well it's ln x(t)

Comment: almost... it's : $ln |x(t)|$. Thus, if the RHS is almost constant equal to $\lambda$, the solution will be $x(t)\approx Ce^{\lambda t}$ tending to 0 is $\lambda <0$ or $+\infty$ if $\lambda>0$. This the beginning of the understanding of the roles of the signs of $M$ and $N$...

Comment: sorry , but how did you get $x(t)\approx Ce^{\lambda t}$

Comment: $\tfrac{x'}{x}=\lambda \implies ln |x(t)|=\lambda t + \ln(K)$ (with $K>0$) $\implies$ (by taking exp of LHS and RHS,) $|x(t)|=exp(\lambda t)exp(K)$ etc.

Comment: I advise you a very good little book: "Dynamical Systems with applications using Matlab" (2nd edition) by Stephen Lynch (Birkhaüser) (http://www.springer.com/la/book/9783319068190)

Comment: well thank you for your suggestion, I have my finals this week ! I don't have alot of time to digest a new book lol